# Using Python, generate 100x100 random matrix whose entries are sampled from the normal distribution.

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, normal-distribution, python

Generate random vectors using numpy.random. Write code in Python that produces a $100 \times 100$ random matrix whose entries are samples from the normal distribution.

---

This is what I produced and am unsure if this is correct. I have a question on normal distribution as well. Should my random numbers come from a certain pool? Such as $[0,1]$ or is it possible to get values out of this range?

[image: This is the code if wrote in Jupyter Notebook]

If anyone knows a better way to post Python code, I would also appreciate that.

Comment: This is probably a better question for https://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Post each line of code with four spaces in front (plus whatever extra indentation some lines have relative to others).

Comment: It is possible (and likely!) to get values out of that range.   https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistribution.html

Comment: @JoshuaWang Thank you. I will keep that in mind. Sadly I need more reputation points to post images, but I can post the code line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is correct. You could do:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hist(a.reshape(-1, 1))
plt.show()
```

to see a histogram which should reflect a bell curve. `a.reshape(-1, 1)` puts the matrix into a single vector.

Comment: You may need a third line, `plt.show()`.